# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder

Tags: java, ms-access, ucanaccess, jackcess

```
package myJavaPrograms;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class AccessDBFiles {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException  {
        Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\TESTFILE\\Database11.accdb");
        Statement s = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable");
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    }
```

> I am getting exception in thread main as Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/lang/builder/CompareToBuilder
>   [image: External Jars added to project]

Comment: Seems like it cant find given class. Actually it should be in commons lang. So, I'd suggest rebuild project or change version of commons lang and logging libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UCanAccess uses Jackcess, and Jackcess uses `commons-lang` (v2.x), not `commons-lang3`. All of the required dependencies for UCanAccess are included in the `lib` folder of the UCanAccess distribution (.bin.zip file).

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using UCanAccess, the pure JDBC driver. This case you have to load this driver:

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
```

Alternatively, you can load the JDBC/ODBC driver class like this:

```
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
```

This case, the URL format is like this:

```
jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=myDB.mdb;
```

Also, don't forget to close the resources: ResultSet, Statement and Connection.

Comment: "Alternatively, you can load the JDBC/ODBC driver class" - Not with Java 8. The JDBC/ODBC Bridge has been removed.